# Link two xml files

Tags: c#, xml

I have two xml files with different structures and need to link them.

XML 1:

```
<Departments>
  <Department Id='D1' />
</Departments>`
```

XML 2:

```
<Faculty Id='F1'>
  <Classrooms><Classroom Name='CR1' /><Classroom Name='CR2' /></Classrooms>
</Faculty>
<Faculty Id='F2'>
  <Classrooms><Classroom Name='CR3' /><Classroom Name='CR4' /></Classrooms>
</Faculty>
```

Now I want to link in a way that if I provide 'CR1' and 'D1' as my inputs, it should return F1. I want to link department (XML 1) and faculty (XML 2). What could be the best way to do it?

Comment: Where and how is D1 represented in XML 2?

Comment: @LueTm I believe it's not at the moment - it is exactly what he wants to accomplish ("I want to link [...]")

Comment: @saloni imo you need to be clearer about your requirements and preconditions, as this is what "the best way" would depend on. And right now we know next to nothing

Comment: @Morawski the best way as in performance wise, less IO operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to change the XML structure I would add a link to the department through an attribute on faculty in XML2 (department="d1" for example).

Comment: Than you probably need some coding. Maybe it's an idea to introduce a third XML file where you store the linkage between the other two files.